# Reload url in onLoadResource

Tags: android, webview, webclient

I'm trying to change http to https url of resources. I tried this :

[image]

But it is not working. I tried print logs. All ok. Is there a way to do this ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You need set WebClient with overriding loading

it looks something like this:

```
 WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
   @Override
  public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    String modifiedUrl = ...;
    super.onPageStarted(view, modifiedUrl, favicon);
  }
};

mWvWebview.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
```

I think it also van be achieved with overriding `onPageStarted()`

Comment: it doesnot work. I want to do that change http method links to https